# Facing Jump of around 80-100 in Id column in SQL Server 2016 which did not have identity but generate number using sequence in code

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Please find the SQL followed to generate new seq number

```
CREAT PROCEDURE [dbo].[axsp_get_next_no_internal_64]  
  @table_name      nvarchar(30),  
  @increment       int = 1,  
  @log_id          BIGINT = 0,  
  @is_use_sequence bit = 1,  
  @new_next_no     bigint OUTPUT  
  
as  
  
SET @new_next_no = 0;  
  
IF @is_use_sequence = 0  
BEGIN  
 DECLARE @next_no_tab table(next_no bigint);  
  
 UPDATE [dbo].[next_no_64] set next_no = next_no + @increment output inserted.next_no into @next_no_tab where table_name = @table_name  
  
 SELECT @new_next_no = next_no - @increment from @next_no_tab  
END  
ELSE  
BEGIN  
DECLARE  
 @first_seq_num sql_variant,  
 @seq_name nvarchar(max) = 'dbo.n_' + @table_name,  
 @sql nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT @retval_out = (NEXT VALUE FOR n_' + @table_name + N')';  
  
IF @increment = 1  
 EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, N'@retval_out bigint OUTPUT', @retval_out=@new_next_no OUTPUT;  
ELSE  
 BEGIN  
  
 EXEC sys.sp_sequence_get_range  
 @sequence_name = @seq_name  
 , @range_size = @increment  
 , @range_first_value = @first_seq_num OUTPUT;  
  
 SELECT  
  @new_next_no = convert(bigint, @first_seq_num);  
 END  
END

create procedure sys.sp_sequence_get_range  
 @sequence_name      nvarchar(776),  
 @range_size         bigint,  
 @range_first_value  sql_variant output,  
 @range_last_value   sql_variant = null output,  
 @range_cycle_count  int = null output,  
 @sequence_increment sql_variant = null output,  
 @sequence_min_value sql_variant = null output,  
 @sequence_max_value sql_variant = null output  
as  
 declare @ret int  
 exec @ret = sys.sp_sequence_get_range_internal @sequence_name, @range_size, @range_first_value output, @range_last_value output,  
  @range_cycle_count output, @sequence_increment output, @sequence_min_value output, @sequence_max_value output  
 return @ret
```

Parameter always goes as  @increment = 1,  @log_id =1,
@is_use_sequence = 1 with table name

I have already read article about sequence chasm (https://sqlity.net/en/792/the-gap-in-the-identity-value-sequence/) but can it be possible with above sequencing as i can see sequencing is solution to this by switching off catching.

But let me know and who can i replicate so i can document for my project.

Comment: FYI, that SQL is open to injection attacks, due to the blind injection of object names into dynamic statements. YOu should *really* be using `QUOTENAME` at a minimum.

Comment: As for gaps, both `SEQUENCE` and `IDENTITY` have the same feature where once a value has been used, it's been used. Gaps are expected for both.

Comment: gap free sequences have always been a bad idea in relational databases, mostly because it is impossible to guarantee unless the execution is serial. See this "Ask Tom" article from way back in 2001 but still relevant:
https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1508205334476

Comment: You can use the `NO CACHE` option, which will prevent jumps after a server restart, but it doesn't prevent issues surrounding uncommitted transactions, as mentioned.

Comment: Thankyou everyone . Yes pretty much confident on the gaps now, It is common Behaviour observed with SQL server. I will check the identity cache with server admin if he can make it off.

Comment: Turning off cache for sequences will seriously slow down input performance.

Answer (score 0):

With a lot of replication, i found when i do the SQL server shutdown directly from active window and then again start MSSQLSERVER Service. In sys.sequences contained table new value is updated with 100+ number and totally replaced what previous value is there.

Due to this whole sequencing logic return number by incrementing the new value. like 104+1 = 105, 106,107 ..etc.
Below are screenshot 1st one is before the server shutdown and 2nd is after server restart.

[image: Before the MSSQLSERVER SHUTDOWN]

[image: After MSSQLSERVER SERVICE RESTART]

So i need to do workaround this sys.sequences sys.sequences contained table or may be i can provide them script so if anytime if someone take server shutdown or restart they can execute the script to reset the start value to what is max value available in table.